# Chrome and Firefox not working in RDP session

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, remote-desktop, remote-access

I have a server and many low end laptops at home. I'm using a single user login (xxx@hotmail.com) to access the server from all laptops using Windows RDP (like the one in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/116016/logging-in-as-the-same-user-multiple-times-in-remote-desktop-windows-server-2008) case).

I'm using Windows 10 on the server and laptops vary from Windows 7 to Windows 10. I'm also using [RDP Wrapper Library](https://github.com/binarymaster/rdpwrap) to access RDP in Windows 10.

Everything works fine except Chrome and Firefox browser. I cannot create multiple sessions of Chrome or Firefox though I use the same account at multiple places. Internet Explorer is the only browser that works fine with this multiple login RDP.

Any suggestions for fixes or modifications to be made?

Comment: FYI: rdpwrap is technically illegal because the Windows license does not allow more than 2 concurrent sessions (one admin and one normal session) and rdpwrap is breaking the license agreement for you.

Comment: @cdavid I was just trying it for my project purpose. but how can Internet Explorer could handle Different Sessions simultaneously where as Chrome and Firefox Couldn't.? That was my question basically.

Comment: My guess would be that there are locks in place that Chrome and Firefox put on the user profiles when starting the first time. Then, when the 2nd session starts, this is a whole new user session for Chrome, so it probably freaks out because 2 user sessions would be reading / writing the same data (race conditions).